# drawing bar chart with chart.js jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, chart.js

I've got question about drawing bar chart in chart.js
Let me explain my problem, I created button and text box where u should give number of elements u want to draw. Next i put data and it should work.

Var options contain options to draw charts.
After options I've got part with creating more field where i can input my data, and when I've got more than 0 elements created button draw appears.
At least I have function with pushing my data into array and drawing, this part doesnt work :( pls help

I done same with pie chart but with different options. Everything was from Chart.js documentation. Can anyone help me to figure it out how to make it work? Thanks :)

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/numeral.js/1.4.5/numeral.min.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>LinkButtonStairs</title>
</head>

<body>
        <div>
            <p>Provide your data here, how many data u need?</p>
            <input type="text" id="someShiet" />
            <input type="button" value="ADD" id="addTextboxes" />
        </div>
        <br><br>

        <div id="textboxContainer">

        </div>

        <canvas id="myChart" height="800" width="400"></canvas>

        <script>

            var boxCounter = 0;
            var data = 0;
            var context = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');

            var options = {
                    scaleBeginAtZero : true,
                    scaleShowGridLines : true,
                    scaleGridLineColor : "rgba(0,0,0,.05)",
                    scaleGridLineWidth : 1,
                    scaleShowHorizontalLines: true,
                    scaleShowVerticalLines: true,
                    barShowStroke : true,
                    barStrokeWidth : 2,
                    barValueSpacing : 5,
                    barDatasetSpacing : 1,
                    legendTemplate : "<ul class=\"<%=name.toLowerCase()%>-legend\"><% for (var i=0; i<datasets.length; i++){%><li><span style=\"background-color:<%=datasets[i].fillColor%>\"></span><%if(datasets[i].label){%><%=datasets[i].label%><%}%></li><%}%></ul>"
                }

            $("#addTextboxes").on("click", function () {
                boxCounter = $("#someShiet").val();
                $("#textboxContainer").html("");
                for (var i = 0; i < $("#someShiet").val() ; i++) {
                    $("#textboxContainer").append('<input type="text" class="chartData" id="whatever' + i + '"/><br><br>');
                }
                if ($("#someShiet").val() > 0)
                    $("#textboxContainer").append('<input type="button" value="Draw" id="drawChart" />');

            });
            $(document).on("click", "#drawChart", function (event) {
                data = new Array();
                for (var i = 0; i < boxCounter ; i++) {
                    data.push({
                        data : $("#whatever").val(),
                        fillColor: "lightblue",
                        labels: $("#whatever").val() + "element"
                    });
                }
                var mybarChartLoc = new Chart(context).Bar(data, options);
            });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The bar data format is different from the pie data format. Also, you haven't included your index in the textbox selector.

You need to change your handler to

```
$(document).on("click", "#drawChart", function (event) {
    data = {
        labels: [],
        datasets: [
            {
                fillColor: "lightblue",
                data: []
            }
        ]
    };
    for (var i = 0; i < boxCounter ; i++) {
        data.labels.push($("#whatever" + i).val() + "element");
        data.datasets[0].data.push($("#whatever" + i).val())
    }
    var mybarChartLoc = new Chart(context).Bar(data, options);
});
```

Comment: thanks for help i did it in other way :) and it works